# How many security rings are used in different Windows operating systems?

Tags: windows, security, memory, kernel

I ask this question, because I am trying tried to search this information for all Windows operating systems (from 9x up to Windows 8, including Windows CE/Embedded), but no success, I didn't get exactly the count of rings in different versions, about memory range and so on.

Some info was in MSDN about native development (KMDF), but only for lower-level work, than Win32, and there was no full info about all rings and accessing each ring.

Could you help me answer this question?

Comment: I don't get it. Do you mean things like Ring0 or Ring3? As far as I know no MS operating system uses more than those two, at least not on x86. And what about "memory range and ect."? Be a lot more specific, please.

Comment: memory range is pretty usable, if you develop drivers for arm/android for example, arm don't have support for rings and provide security modes with memory range ( http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/Chdddhea.html )

Comment: In Windows we are talking about "user mode" and "kernel mode" (ring3 and ring0 respectively).

Comment: and what about ARM && Windows 8 ? Windows 8 can run on ARM, but ARM doesn't have security ring support and so what about your words about two rings?

Comment: kernel mode in Windows is ring 0? really? and tcpip.sys and other drivers, which loads in native mode are in ring0? supervisor? and I can launch some interrupts for x86 processor in my *.sys driver, if I develop some *.sys driver? As I have tested , there are many limits for native-development for Windows in C++ compiler, maybe it's not really kernel and is really ring1 or ring2?

Comment: Pretty pointless to ask about Windows 8 on ARM cores, nobody has seen it yet.  But it will probably use the built-in support, google "arm supervisor mode".

Comment: @user1131997: Device drivers live in ring0, so yes, you can do practically *anything* within those. What exactly have you tested that you couldn't because of hardware security restrictions?

Comment: @niklas-baumstark I have tested writing own usb driver for webcam/Windows, using kmdf, which compiles in native mode for Windows and using Native API ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_API ), some interupts for immediatly reboot ( calling some INT with code ) was declined in my test

Comment: @user1131997: I didn't say the Native API would let you do anything, but the *CPU*.

Comment: @niklas-baumstark but I have said, that device drivers live in ring0, as you they can live well in ring2 in Windows family as all another *.sys drivers. And about using full power of CPU I must access ring0, right? so only in this ring0 I'm able to all capabilities of CPU manually

Comment: @user1131997: I said that device drivers usually live in ring0 on Windows, period.

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark - Just leaving this as a comment, and it is more of historical interest than anything else and certainly doesn't answer the question which seems to be muddled, but some MS operating systems do use other than two rings. DOS with himem.sys runs in protected mode with only one ring - everything is in ring 0. WinCE on x86 uses more than two (from memory, it might use four but I think only three). The tiny realtime bits of the kernel run in 0, the rest of the kernel in 1, and user mode (including most drivers) in ring 3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No major operating system (at least not on desktop) nowadays uses more than 2 rings, for the simple reason that on *the one major architecture*, the modern, efficient way of doing syscalls (e.g. `SYSENTER`) exclusively supports going from ring-3 to ring-0 and back.

Which means, if you are going to support more than two rings, and Intel support is a consideration, you will buy a rather minor (and often disputed) advantage security-wise at the price having to write separate implementations of *completely different* security models -- for the same identical OS.
Which, frankly, lies somewhere in between "maintenance nightmare" and "madness".

Answer (score 2):

Protection rings are a construct of the x86 processor architecture, and not of any particular operating system. In the case of Windows (and Linux), kernel mode runs in ring 0 and user mode runs in ring 3. Rings 1 and 2 are no used in a standard Windows system.

Comment: Multics has 8th rings, but Multics was developed not for x86 as I understand.

So, what is protection rings in processor? Just another registers as "ebx, sse" and else but for only security rings?

So, processor supports it, but if OS is designed in the way , that it can NOT to use them, so security rings isn't just a stuff , which provides CPU, but an OS too, right?

STOP! And ring 2 in Widnows!!! Ring 2 for privileged code (user programs with I/O access permissions ) , native development ( lower level, than Win32 , which uses kernel mode framework foundation ).

Comment: So *nix system supports 2 rings and Windows supports totally 3 rings ( while our discussion )...

Android which is system for ARM now doesn't support the idea of rings, Intel has launched with Google project, where Android will work on ATOM processors, may be there will be so idea realsed for Android, right?

Comment: It sounds like you're confusing a lot of different concepts. At a fundamental level, rings are just hardware-based privilege levels. You can do more things at ring 0 as you can at ring 3. You may want to do some background reading on this (start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(computer_security)). A complete discussion on this would require much more text than is appropriate for a StackOverflow discussion.

Comment: what exaclty concepts have I confused? As in wiki, there is info about ring2 in Windows, also we know, that a man can write own OS like Minix, and if in OS there isn't any piece of code, which supports idea of secure rings , so what? if rings are supported in CPU, but OS can not to support it, no?

Comment: @user1131997: Some operating systems indeed use different hardware rings for different layers of the software (e.g. kernel runs in ring0, drivers in ring1+2, user software in ring3 etc.). However, most modern, monolithic OSes simply execute all kernel and driver code in ring0 and all user code in ring3 (this is called kernel-land and userland, respectively).